# Keep script active between and during page change/refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, client-side, adsense

I'm not an expert in JavaScript or JQuery and can't seem to figure this out:
Is it possible to keep a script active (for example a cryptominer that runs at 50% while you're browsing the website) between page changes or refreshes.
For the project I'm working on it's not possible to store this value somewhere and pick it back up later to start it again (and possibly correct for the time the load was taking). It actually has to run.

Or is the only way to keep the main page active with the script in it and refresh only (part of) the content?

If this last option is the only way, does anyone know if Google Adsense will pick up the new content as a new page or will it think of it as still the same page?

Any insight is appreciated.

Comment: No, that is not possible. You can however store data in localstorage or cookies and access it across multiple page changes/refreshes.

Comment: Not really. You can do a very limited amount of background work with service workers.

Comment: What do you mean by "refresh" ?  Updating DOM elements?  Or a page load?  If you're referring to a page load, then you should be looking at a server side language to manage your data between page loads.  Or, use AJAX + jQuery to update your current page.

Comment: @KevinB: That's pretty much what I thought. localstorage will not do for this however

Comment: @devlincarnate: By refresh I meant F5 or something. Each time the page reloads.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only tool you have available (Without involving extensions, or anything the user needs to download), is [service workers](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers/).

As @KevinB points out, you can also use `localStorage` or cookies in order to keep data between pages (But this will require at least one page being open in order to keep running).

Additionally, depending on how much coding is involved: You should consider a 1 page application design (Sorta like facebook). You really wouldn't be navigating to other pages, just reloading content in place on a single page. This would allow your scripts to continue to run in between pages (As the content would be delivered via ajax, instead of navigating away).

Comment: LocalStorage is not an option for what I'm trying to do. It cannot stop at all costs. There's a ton of complex things happening constantly and it there's too much to all put into localStorage and then pick it up again (and ofset for the time lost between pages).
I think the only viable option is to  put the script into a container and update the content through AJAX or something. This way I can keep the  page from reloading and keep the script running.

Comment: @Nahbyr This sounds like something you may want to do server side, or at least optimize so it runs more efficiently. Without knowing more into it, my answer pretty much sums up your options.

Comment: A bit more info: it's a script to cryptomine on the client's pc. The website will require a lot of switching between pages, but this would interupt the mining each time, requiring time to load up again etc.
I'm trying to keep the application 'free' without annoying ads all over the place, so please don't judge me :)

Comment: Depending on how much coding is involved: You should consider a 1 page application design (Sorta like facebook). You really wouldn't be navigating to other pages, just reloading content in place on a single page. Only other way is to use a service worker: And doing this kind of stuff would pretty much likely get your site red flagged by google.

Comment: Yes, I just read through the link you supplied and I was making faces all the way to the bottom.
It's pretty much what you suggested in your last comment I think. One page and reload parts of the content to keep the script running.

You wouldn't be knowledgeable what this would do for Google Adsense by any chance?

Comment: No sir, unfortunately not.

Comment: Ok, I'll ask somewhere else for that then, thanks for the help you  did provide.
Could you update your answer so I can give you my cookies?